# How can I listen git specific changes

Tags: node.js, git, maven

please share some best practice regarding the topic.

**Situation:** We have product running in VM.
In our product we have a multi projects, which are using our libraries.

**Task:** Need to automatically update versions of changed library projects in corresponding dependent projects.

*Example:* Changes in library pom.xml files will trigger changes in dependent projects where using the libraries.

**Action:** Investigated web hooks, git hooks, maven bom (this one is good for centralizing libraries)

**Result:** This solutions not working for us.

**P.S.** Currently thinking to have a node js script which will be run in VM periodically, checking changes in our library repository.
If the libraries version are changed, then will change the version in dependent projects and push the changes.

Another solution is using of [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html)

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html) seems the best one.

Thanks [ruhong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519951/ruhong) for tips [How to display dependency updates only for release versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146719/how-to-display-dependency-updates-only-for-release-versions).